# Issue migrating from azure cloud services classic to azure cloud services extended support

Tags: azure

When validating a migration to ARM from ASM, I get an error regarding a deployment that reads:
"Deployment 7b4aef49858a466dggc865787h232232 in cloud service legacyApplicationName must be within a virtual network to be migrated."
Problem is that the deployment is not accessible and cannot be opened.

Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

I have read the MS recommended documentation and googled the issue to no avail.